# Why isnt both arguements of object displayed when program is run?

Tags: java

I would like to know why that when I create an object with no arguments the scale is NOT displayed but the degree is! Want to know why or what can be done to fix this? Thanks!

MAIN

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Temperature one = new Temperature();

    }
}
```

CLASS

```
public class Temperature
{
   final String DEGREE = "\u00B0" ;

   private int degree ;
   private char scale ;

   public Temperature(){
       int degree = 0 ;
       char scale = 'C' ;

       System.out.printf("%s", this) ;
   }


   public String toString(){
        return degree + DEGREE + scale;
   }
```

Comment: thank you sir, I see that now! What shadowing(just to be clear) is that I am reiterating the variables? the this means to use these variables her when there are no arguments? correct

Comment: You're not _reiterating the variables_, you're declaring completely new, completely unrelated variables and assigning them values, while your fields are left with their default value.

Comment: Ok so even though the original code declares new variables why does it print the 0 and not the c

Comment: The default value for an `int` is 0. The default value for a `char` is `'\0'` which is not a displayable character.

Comment: ahh thank you sir. so what I had was saying to use the private variables for the class and that's why we use this